# ASP.net Ajax Unknown Web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

So, I have done this before and made many many ajax calls 
For some reason ***this*** one doesn't work =(

**What do I need to change to get this one to work?**

Previously I had an internal server error 500, but after pasting some working code and renaming methods to shorter names finally it changed over to this error of Unknown web method.

### Setup

I am using jQuery to make Ajax calls to WebMethods in my Codebehind for my ASP.NET page.

Here is my C# WebMethod

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string viewApps(string foo)
    {
        string x = "";

        //130 lines of useful code.

        x = "0";
        return x;
    }
```

Here is the Javascript/jQuery doing the ajax call. It is in side a   with all my other ajax calls. The other ones work. This one does not. It triggered by an onclick event in the html.

```
        function viewApps() {

            var food = "hamburger";
            $.ajax(
            {
                //send selected makes
                type: "POST",
                url: "MassUpdater.aspx/viewApps",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{foo:" + food + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                //process the response
                //and populate the list
                success: function (msg) {

                    //just for show
                },
                error: function (e) {

                    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
                    $('#result').innerHTML = "unavailable";
                }
            });

//to be uncommented later when functionality works.

            // populateBrakeConfigs();
            //  populateBedConfigs();
            //   populateBodyStyleConfigs();
            //   populateSpringConfigs();
            //   populateSteeringConfigs();
            //  populateWheeleBase();
            //   populateTransmission();
            //   populateDriveTypes();

            function populateBrakeConfigs() { }
            function populateBedConfigs() { }
            function populateBodyStyleConfigs() { }
            function populateSpringConfigs() { }
            function populateSteeringConfigs() { }
            function populateWheeleBase() { }
            function populateTransmission() { }
            function populateDriveTypes() { }

        }
```

The ajax error looks like this:

[image: Ajax error]

I am also willing to provide any additional code or information about my project upon request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer unfortunately is that somehow the static keyword got left out of the WebMethod, therefore the ajax call cannot find it.